# Android - When sending images to the server in vertical, they are rotated although the preview in the mobile looks good

Tags: android, image, rotation

The preview on the phone looks good before sending the file, but once it is received on the server and reloaded on the mobile is rotated vertical images.

```
public static File saveBitmapTemporarily(Bitmap finalBitmap, int extension, ExifInterface oldExif) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    FileUtils.createFolder(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + BuildConfig.STORAGE_DIR));

    File myDir = new File(root + BuildConfig.STORAGE_DIR + "/");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname;
    if (extension == IMAGE_FORMAT_JPG_JPEG) {
        fname = "file-reduced.jpg";
    } else {
        fname = "file-reduced.png";
    }
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        if (extension == IMAGE_FORMAT_JPG_JPEG) {
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        } else {
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
}
```

Comment: paste your code snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have a go yourself and post up what you've tried, people will be able to help you. [Look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @kiketurry... Here you have what I did to solve this problem. You should store the width and height dimension in the exif data of the photo so that the server knows how to orient it, but **it can only be in jpg**

```
if (extension == IMAGE_FORMAT_JPG_JPEG) {
    ExifInterface oldExif = null;
    try {
        oldExif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ExifInterface newExif;
        newExif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
        newExif.setAttribute("ImageLength", String.valueOf(finalBitmap.getHeight()));
        newExif.setAttribute("ImageWidth", String.valueOf(finalBitmap.getWidth()));
        if (oldExif != null) {
            String exifOrientation = oldExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            if (exifOrientation != null) {
                newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, exifOrientation);
            }
        }
        newExif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.